# SQL : how to check if a column value has all elements from a string array

Tags: sql

I have a table where a column called `Phrase` has a sentence.

For example :

```
ID  |     Phrase    |
----+---------------+
 1  | I can do it   |
 2  | Where is that |
```

I also have another table which has keywords. For example :

```
select keyword 
from keywords
```

returns

```
    ID | Keywords |
    ---+----------+
     1 |    I     |
     2 |    can   |
     3 |    do    |
     4 |    it    |
```

How can I can check if the `phrase` column for a given row has all matching keywords. Something like:

```
select * 
from table 
where phrase like '%I%' 
  and phrase like '%do%' 
  and phrase like '%can%' 
  and phrase like '%it%'
```

Thanks

Comment: Would you always be checking _all_ keywords from the `keywords` table?

Comment: Not really. The whole idea is t o get certain keywords and check its occurrence in phrase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following to get the phrase that contains all of the keywords listed in keyword table:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.Phrase 
FROM table_name T JOIN keyword K
ON T.Phrase LIKE CONCAT('%',K.Keywords,'%')
GROUP BY T.ID, T.Phrase
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM keyword)
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/i41f_RYm).

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit tricky but by using `String_Split` it can be handled like this:

```sql
SELECT ph.Id,
       ph.Phrase
FROM
(
    SELECT Id,
           Phrase,
           value
    FROM Phrases
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Phrase, ' ')
) ph
    LEFT JOIN Keywords keys
        ON keys.Keyword = ph.value
GROUP BY ph.Id,
         ph.Phrase
HAVING SUM(   CASE
                  WHEN keys.Keyword IS NULL THEN
                      1
                  ELSE
                      0
              END
          ) = 0;
```

Comment: Hi. I'm going with the other solution since it's concise but your solution works as expected as well. Thank you !

Comment: @DinoMyte Thanks, As you know there is one point in the other solution that it doesn't detect the ``word`` for example if there is a keyword ``i`` it will detect any word contains ``i`` like ``init, child, it``, but it's nice and concise :)